# Minimal interface for a Promises/A+ promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am writing a JavaScript code generator and want to avoid a dependency to a specific Promises/A+ framework. Instead of using callbacks in methods/functions, I want to return promises.

What is the minimal required interface of a promise object so that it works with any Promises/A+ library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only required interface for a **Promises/A+** is implementing the `then` method.

This is specified here: http://promisesaplus.com/

This makes sense, since A+ is only about making promises *interoperability*, as a standard it only specifies the bare minimum for that.

You can `.catch` with:

```
promise.catch(err){

});
// is the same as the following, which is required by the Promises/A+ standard.
promise.then(null, function(err){

});
```

Comment: @RicoSuter the specification knows nothing about `.catch` https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec

Comment: @RicoSuter `catch` is required for a promise implementation to be compliant with the ES2015 (ES6) standard. Native ES2015 promises have `.catch` and also have a `Promise.all` and `Promise.race`. Practically all promise implementations I know except two (mpromise used in Mongoose until recently, and jQuery) sport `.catch`

Comment: The reason `catch` isn't in A+ is that you can express `catch` with `then` but not vice versa - that is, a one argument `then` + `catch` _cannot_ express some scenarios  that two argument `then` can - namely scenarios where you have _both_ handlers.

Comment: I've updated my question, does the code meet the requirements?

Comment: @RicoSuter no of course it doesn't, the `then` method has to be very robust, also please don't change questions on StackOverflow after you've asked them. Ask a new one if you have a new question

Comment: Like, 40% of the point of promises is catch safety and error propagation, another 40% is chaining (you can return a promise from onFulfilled or onRejected. So even if we ignore how robust the spec is to assimilation it's still wrong.